# Highstock (Highcharts) Tooltip without delimiter scale y values

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm trying show multiples values in **tooltip**.

In old version of Highstock (2.0.3) it's working fine!

But in last release, not work =(

**Working fine version with highstock-2.0.3:**
[image: Working fine version with highstock-2.0.3]

```
        <!-- ##### !!! HERE - WORKING FINE !!! ##### -->
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/2.0.3/highstock.js"></script> <!-- OLD Version -->

    <!--script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script--> <!-- NEW Version -->

    <div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
        $(function () {
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
        type: 'line',
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        backgroundColor: null,   


        events: {
            load: function() {
                valueX('#xxx');
            }
        }
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: [1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014],
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        labels: {
          y: 30,              
          style: {
            fontSize: '13px'
          }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        opposite: false,
        gridLineWidth: 0.5,
        labels: {
          enabled: true,

        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
         min: 0,
         max: 85,
         startOnTick: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,

    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'horizontal',
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',


    },
    series: [
        {
            animation: false,
            name: 'A',

            min: 0,
            max: 1000,
            data: [113.000,153.000,156.000,155.000,123.000,109.000,95.000,67.000,111.000,106.000,95.000,88.000,88.000,107.000,90.000,79.000,59.000,65.000,66.000],
            type: 'line',
            showInLegend: false,
            color: 'none', // color 'transparent' não funciona no IE 8
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true,
                pointFormat: '{point.y} AAA <br />',
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        },
        {
            animation: false,
            name: 'B',
            data: [196429.000,192757.000,185378.000,186675.000,179462.000,167270.000,165125.000,157333.000,159636.000,160324.000,153598.000,147554.000,151092.000,149217.000,152051.000,152902.000,153945.000,155758.000,159915.000],
            type: 'line',
            showInLegend: false,
            color: 'none', // color 'transparent' não funciona no IE 8
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true,
                pointFormat: '{point.y} BBB<br/>',
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        },
        {
            animation: false,
            name: 'C',
            data: [57.530,79.370,84.150,90.10,68.540,65.160,57.530,42.580,69.530,66.120,61.850,59.640,58.240,71.710,59.190,51.670,38.330,41.730,41.270],
                shared: true,
            type: 'line',
            lineWidth: 5,
            tooltip: {
                useHTML: true,
          showInLegend: false,
                pointFormat: '{point.y} CCC<br/>',
                valueDecimals: 2
            },

        },
        {
            data: "[null]",
            visible: false,
            showInLegend: false
        }
    ]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mad7a8b1/1/

========================================

**Not Working with last version highstock-5.0.1:**
[image: Not Working with last version highstock-5.0.1]

```
        <!-- ##### !!! HERE - NOT WORKING !!! ##### -->
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script> <!-- NEW Version -->

    <!--script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/2.0.3/highstock.js"></script--> <!-- OLD Version -->

    <div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
        $(function () {
      $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
          type: 'line',
          plotBorderWidth: 0,
          backgroundColor: null,   


          events: {
              load: function() {
                  valueX('#xxx');
              }
          }
      },

      xAxis: {
          categories: [1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014],
          title: {
              text: ''
          },
          labels: {
            y: 30,              
            style: {
              fontSize: '13px'
            }
          }
      },
      yAxis: {
          opposite: false,

          labels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {

            }
          },
          title: {
              text: ''
          },
           min: 0,
           max: 85,
           startOnTick: false
      },
      tooltip: {
          shared: true,

      },
      legend: {
          layout: 'horizontal',
          align: 'center',
          verticalAlign: 'bottom',
          borderWidth: 0,

      },
      series: [
          {
              animation: false,
              name: 'A',

              min: 0,
              max: 1000,
              data: [113.000,153.000,156.000,155.000,123.000,109.000,95.000,67.000,111.000,106.000,95.000,88.000,88.000,107.000,90.000,79.000,59.000,65.000,66.000],
              type: 'line',
              showInLegend: false,
              color: 'none', // color 'transparent' não funciona no IE 8
              marker: {
                  enabled: false,
                  states: {
                      hover: {
                          enabled: false
                      }
                  }
              },
              tooltip: {
                  shared: true,
                  useHTML: true,
                  pointFormat: '{point.y} AAA <br />',
                  valueDecimals: 2
              }
          },
          {
              animation: false,
              name: 'B',
              data: [196429.000,192757.000,185378.000,186675.000,179462.000,167270.000,165125.000,157333.000,159636.000,160324.000,153598.000,147554.000,151092.000,149217.000,152051.000,152902.000,153945.000,155758.000,159915.000],
              type: 'line',
              showInLegend: false,
              color: 'none', // color 'transparent' não funciona no IE 8
              marker: {
                  enabled: false,
                  states: {
                      hover: {
                          enabled: false
                      }
                  }
              },
              tooltip: {
                  shared: true,
                  useHTML: true,
                  pointFormat: '{point.y} BBB<br/>',
                  valueDecimals: 2
              }
          },
          {
              animation: false,
              name: 'C',
              data: [57.530,79.370,84.150,90.10,68.540,65.160,57.530,42.580,69.530,66.120,61.850,59.640,58.240,71.710,59.190,51.670,38.330,41.730,41.270],
                  shared: true,
              type: 'line',
              lineWidth: 5,
              tooltip: {
                  useHTML: true,
            showInLegend: false,
                  pointFormat: '{point.y} CCC<br/>',
                  valueDecimals: 2
              },

          },
          {
              data: "[null]",
              visible: false,
              showInLegend: false
          }
      ]
                                      });
                                  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vtju3n4a/2/

Please: check head includes to view the JSs. ;-)

Thanks!

Comment: 2.0.3 was a looooong time ago :)  I would suggest either working the additional data into the primary series' data array, and reference it in the tooltip formatter, or hold the data in external arrays, and reference it in the tooltip formatter. Creating hidden series seems like a lot of overhead for getting data into the tooltip

Comment: OK @jlbriggs!  I'll try it! Do you have a simple example? Thanks!!

Comment: example jsfiddle.net/vtju3n4a/4

Comment: Awesome! tnx!
My problem is the loop to fill tooltip series on php... :(